# Get corresponding physical disk drives of mountpoints with WMI queries?

Tags: c#, wmi

Is there a way to retrieve a connection between a mountpoint (a volume which is mounted into the file system instead of mounted to a drive letter) and its belonging physical disk drive(s) with WMI?

For example I have got a volume mountpoint on a W2K8 server which is mounted to “C:\Data\” and the mountpoint is spreaded on the physical disk drives 2, 4, and 5 of the server (the Data Management of the Server Manager shows that) but I cannot find a way to get this to know by using WMI.

Volumes which have got a drive letter can be connected with the WMI-Classes Win32_DiskDrive --> Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition --> Win32_DiskPartition --> Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition --> Win32_LogicalDisk – but the problem is, that volume mountpoints aren’t listed in the class Win32_LogicalDisk, they are only listed in Win32_Volume. And I did not find a way to connect the class Win32_Volume with the class Win32_DiskDrive – there are missing some linking classes.

Does anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 2):

The only way I know of is using the Win32 API to help.

You [open a handle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28VS.85%29.aspx) to the volume using [Win32_Volume](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394515%28VS.85%29.aspx).DeviceID, modified slightly. You can open a handle to the volume using the format:

```
\\.\Volume{[GUID]}
```

You then need to issue [IOCTL_VOLUME_GET_VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365194%28VS.85%29.aspx) on the open handle to retrieve a [VOLUME_DISK_EXTENTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365727%28VS.85%29.aspx) structure. This structure will contain a list of physical disk ids for the volume.

Using these disk ids you can query WMI on [Win32_DiskDrive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394132%28VS.85%29.aspx).Index to get the matching disk.