# Getting manufacturer serialnumber of system harddrive with WMI

Tags: c++, wmi, wmi-query

I want to get the manufacturer serialnumber of my system HDD using WMI in my c++ project.

I am already able to query the SerialNumber from the Win32_DiskDrive Class. 
However, this returns four serial numbers because I have four HDD. I only want to know the HDD serialnumber of my system disk but I am not able to format the right query.

Anyone done this before and knows how to construct this query?

Comment: Ask your self what makes the system disk a system disk. It's the partitioning. Have a look at [Win32_DiskPartition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394135(v=vs.85).aspx) and get the system _partition_.

Comment: What I want to do is get the relation between the c: partition and de manufacturer serial number of the disk which this partition is on. Win32_DiskPartition does not provide all this info.

Comment: 'Win32_DiskPartition does not provide all this info' Of course not. But it holds the Disk Index which identifies the **Disk** on which the partition lays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to figure out what is your `SystemDrive` and then query other WMI table to get the `serialNumber`. WMI keeps serialnumber in many tables, you have to make a better choice regarding which table can fulfill your use case. If serialNumber is your only use case then query `Win32_LogicalDisk`, if not, write a comment and we can work from there :)

```
Select SystemDrive  from Win32_OperatingSystem

Select VolumeSerialNumber  FROM Win32_LogicalDisk where (DriveType = '2' or DriveType = '3') AND deviceid= '<SystemDrive>'
```

**Updated**

```
Select  Index from Win32_DiskPartition where BootPartition ='TRUE'
Select  SerialNumber from Win32_DiskDrive where index='<Index>'
```

**Note: Give it a dry run for couple of machines.**

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I need the SerialNumber from Win32_DiskDrive.

Comment: Hello Amit, Your answer was very helpfull. I do not have enough rep to mark this as the answer. The only thing I came accros that I have a dual boot system(Win8 en Win10) and both OS are on a seperate disk. When testing my code both systems returned the same bootpartition. So I was not able to get the serialnumber of my Win10 disk when in Win10 and the same for Win8. For my use case the solution is good but it was not what I originally planned. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

#### To get your System *HDD*, first you have to find out which Hard **Disk** holds your System *Partition*.

---

Use [Win32_DiskPartition](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394135(v=vs.85).aspx) to retrieve the `DiskIndex` Property and use it to query [Win32_DiskDrive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394132%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with it's `Index` property.

Both are `Uint32`.

[This SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5664841/4068240) describes a way of retrieving DiskDrives associated to volumes.

Also ["How can I correlate logical drives and physical Drives" on TechNet](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2005/05/23/how-can-i-correlate-logical-drives-and-physical-disks/) may help.

Answer (score 0):

1.GetSystemDirectory() get system Partition.For example, C:\Windows\System32 and C: is System partition.

2.Get DiskIndex of System partition from Win32_DiskPartition

3.Get SerialNumber from Win32_DiskDrive which DiskIndex is step 2